# Why Does The Browser Hang When Updating The Progress Bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Problem: I have some code that runs and it needs to periodically update a progress bar. It seems to work fine until I get to part of my code where the update occurs inside a for loop.**

After the hangup, the progress bar will update to whatever it was supposed to be after the for loop. For instance in this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Button1').click(function(){
        $("#Progressbar").val(0); //reset to 0
        for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
            $("#Progressbar").val(i/1000);
            //if(i === 50000){
            //  alert("Half Way There");
            //}
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="Button1">Simulate Progress</button>
    <progress id="Progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>
</body>
</html>
```

My browser (Firefox) will hang-up once the button is pressed and after a couple of seconds display a 100% complete progress bar. If you uncomment the code, you will see that the progress bar is 50% complete when the alert shows up.

Why does it hang like that and not produce a smooth progress update? I tried playing around with Web Workers, but I saw pretty much the same response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript runs in a single thread. You are keeping it so busy looping that it doesn't have time to go off and repaint the page.

Use an iterator with `setTimeout` or `setInterval` instead.

Comment: For some reason, I was not thinking about the repainting of the image taking time. I changed the code to check only a few times in the for loop to redraw the progress bar instead of every iteration and it works like a charm. Thanks.